# SQL sequence updating column in reverse order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column `cohort_number` in a table with sequential values from 1 to x (in this case 42) using a seq as below.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq start with 1 increment by 1 no maxvalue no cycle

UPDATE t1
SET cohort_number = next value for seq, instance_number = x.instanceNumber 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id, 
    1 instanceNumber 
    FROM t1
) x 

DROP SEQUENCE seq
```

However on update rather than the first row cohort_number = 1, second row = 2 and so on, the first row cohort_column = 42, second row cohort_column = 2. I.e it appears that the update is being processed from the last entry in the select result rather than the first. Is there anyway around this?

I've also tried with ROW_NUMBER as below, but every value for the cohort_column is set to 1, which I believe is due to `id` having no duplicate values (but I'm guessing here)

```
UPDATE t1
SET cohort_number = x.cohort_number, instance_number = x.instance_number 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as cohort_number,
    1 instance_number 
    FROM t1
) x
```

Comment: Does that update statement executes correctly? It's trying to update T1 but it's in a subquery, should be out of scope.

Comment: Yeah, its probably where I've obfuscated the table name, variables etc incorrectly, before posting the question

Comment: Your second query is invalid since the alias t1 exists inside the derived table x and is not visible outside of x. Now would be a good time to post a simple script that demonstrates your problem that everyone can use as a common starting point. But perhaps this is no reason to actually store a value at all - sounds much more like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange and proprietary UPDATE ... FROM syntax makes my head hurt.

This:

```
UPDATE t1
SET cohort_number = x.cohort_number, instance_number = x.instance_number 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as cohort_number,
    1 instance_number 
    FROM t1
) x
```

Doesn't work, because you're updating T1, without correlating it with x, and your're not updating x.  Either would work.

I find it much easier to write a `SELECT` query that returns all the rows that will be updated, along with the new values for columns to be updated.  Then update that:

```
with x as
(
    SELECT id, 
    cohort_number
    instance_number,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as new_cohort_number,
    1 new_instance_number 
    FROM t1
)
update x set cohort_number = new_cohort_number, instance_number = new_instance_number
```

Comment: Cheers, was banging my head against a brick wall here.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use a sequence for this?  Just use `row_number()`:

```
UPDATE toupdate
    SET cohort_number = seqnum,
        instance_number = new_instanceNumber 
    FROM (SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) as seqnum
                 1 as new_instanceNumber 
          FROM t1
         ) toupdate;
```

Comment: I've tried with row_number but I seem to be doing something wrong... I'll update the question to show what I've tried.

Comment: @Dave0504 . . . I don't get why this would work, except for the typo (now fixed) around `t.*`.

Comment: It didn't, the accepted answer shows where I was going wrong.Cheers.